# How do i stop the injection of styles from other components into my web component that uses ShadowDom

Tags: angular

I use web components with ShadowDom in my angular project.
But all styles from other components with default view encapsulation are added to these components:

[image: Image of code]

The style from "random-normal-box" is added to "web-component-button".
It doesn't affect the components style, but is unnecessary and probably slows down the app. Especially when the number of components grows.

How do I prevent this from happening?

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rewbnr)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing is caused by Angular's default ViewEncapsulation strategy, which is `Emulated`. This strategy emulates the behavior of Shadow DOM by preprocessing (and renaming) CSS code to effectively scope the CSS to the component's view. The Angular compiler adds unique attributes to all elements and CSS rules, effectively scoping the CSS rules to the component's view.

However, when you use `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`, Angular doesn't preprocess the CSS, but instead relies on the Shadow DOM to provide style encapsulation. Shadow DOM isolates styles to the component that declares them, so styles don't bleed in or out of the component.

The issue here seems to be that Angular is applying styles from `RandomNormalBoxComponent` to `WebComponentButton`. This could be due to the usage of `standalone: true` in your component decorators, which is not a recognized property within the Angular `@Component` decorator as of my knowledge.

In Angular, there are three types of View Encapsulation:

1. `ViewEncapsulation.None`: No shadow DOM is created, and styles are globally applied to the entire application.
2. `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`: This is the default. Angular emulates the behavior of the shadow DOM. Styles are scoped to the component, but no shadow DOM is created.
3. `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`: A shadow DOM is created for the component, and styles are scoped to it.

If you don't want styles from one component to bleed into another, you should use `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` (or `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` if you can't use the shadow DOM for some reason).

Here is how you would update your components:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-random-normal-box',
  template: `
  <div class="random-normal-box">
    Random normal box
  </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    .random-normal-box{
      background-color: darkseagreen;
      padding: 0.5em;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }
  `,
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
export class RandomNormalBoxComponent {}
```

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-web-component-button',
  template: `
  <button>
    Just a button
  </button>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    button {
      background-color: lightsteelblue;
      padding: 0.5em;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }    
  `,
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
export class WebComponentButton {}
```

In the example above, I've set the `encapsulation` property to `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` for both components, which should prevent styles from bleeding between them.

Comment: Please add citations from a reputable source, like the Angular docs. You are giving lots of information without any possibility to proof your statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can define you component `scss` in your component itself and stop leaking styles into your other compoenents from your component itself. For example refer the below snippet :

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: 'your-component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom, // Specify ViewEncapsulation property here
  styles: [] // Provide component specific styles here or or name scss file
})
export class YourComponent {
  // Component code
}
```

> Refer angular style guide for more reference [here](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide).